# I think my Apache Tomcat cant find web.xml in struts 1.3

Tags: jsp, web-config, struts-1

I am new to struts and starting with Struts 1.3 , Apache Tomcat 7 and jdk 1.6 .

This is my simple JSP file login.jsp :

```
<%@page import="org.apache.struts.faces.util.StrutsContext"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %> 
<html:form action="/login.do" focus="username">
<table>
<tr>
<th align="right">Username:</th>
<td align="left"><html:text property="username" maxlength="12"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<html:submit/>
</html:form>
```

this is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0"
metadata-complete="true">  

<display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
<description>
  Welcome to Tomcat
</description>
     <servlet>
         <servlet-name>TRS</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
                    <param-name>config</param-name>
                    <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>TRS</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


<jsp-config>
<taglib>
   <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
   <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
</jsp-config>
<!-- Struts Tag Library Descriptors -->
</web-app>
```

After I startup tomcat and run the jsp file I get this error :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /test/WebContent/index.jsp (line: 8, column: 56) File "/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" not found
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:132)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:166)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1425)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:644)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I defined struts-html.tld in web.xml but this error said that cant find this TLD file. I`ve already put *.tld , *.jar ,*.xml and *.jsp in correct location.

TLD file in WEB-INF,
XML file in WEB-INF,
JAR file in WEB-INF/lib,

I really appreciate if anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this will help you out, but my jsp pages use

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
```

instead of

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
```

I'm running on Tomcat 6 and don't have to configure my taglibs in web.xml if I place them in /META-INF/my.tld and refer to them in my jsps with

```
<%@ taglib uri="/META-INF/my.tld" prefix="my"%>
```

Hope this helps you...

****edit****

To solve the "java.lang.NullPointerException: Module 'null' not found." problem paste this snippet in your "action-mappings" section in struts-config.xml

```
    <action path="/login" type="my.app.web.LoginAction" validate="false" name="loginForm">
        <forward name="SUCCESS" path="/login.jsp" />
    </action>
```

and this one into your "form-beans" section:

```
<form-bean name="loginForm" type="my.app.web.LoginForm" />
```

Then create a struts action like this one (LoginAction.java):

```
package my.app.web;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class LoginAction extends BaseAction {

    @Override
    protected ActionForward run(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
                LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm) form;
        return mapping.findForward("SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

Furthermore you need your input form (LoginForm.java):

```
package my.app.web;

import org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorForm;

public class LoginForm extends ValidatorForm {

    private Integer username;

    public Integer getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(Integer username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Open your login page in your browser by typing http://localhost:8080/myApp/login.do

Comment: thanks alot GreenTurtle. I really appreciate your help. I try the same code uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" instead of uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" , but I got this error :
Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:567)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:471)
 
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Module 'null' not found.

Comment: Maybe the info here will help you: [http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ModuleNull](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ModuleNull)

Comment: But for all my applications I use this in my web.xml: <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup> for my struts servlet. But I'm really not sure on this...

Comment: Another idea while searching answers for your problem: Do you have commons-chain-1.1.jar included in your /WEB-INF/lib/ ? This lib seems to be required in older 1.3 releases of Struts - like my version 1.3.8

Comment: Dear GreenTurtle , I checked <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup> and <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> and <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>. but still I have MODUL 'null' NOT FOUND error. I also check commons-chain-1.1.jar in my WEB-INF/lib ! I read the link you introduce to me. I think I accessed a JSP page directly without going through an action. but i dont know how to fix the problem, I mean I dont know how should I access a JSP through an action. I really really appreciate your help. it is very nice of you.

Comment: Ok, then we got it. You accessed a JSP directly. I'll post the solution in my answer above.

Comment: thank you very very much. I did all thing you said but it cannot find login.do. Apache says that : The requested resource (/test/login.do) is not available.

Comment: Did you adjust your package declarations? Are there any compiler errors in your IDE (Eclipse for example) or when your Tomcat is starting? If not, please post your complete struts-config.xml and give me full paths to your LoginAction, LoginForm and JSP.

Comment: please give me a mail address so i can post my files. I am really confused. I did everything I could but there is no change. It is very nice of you.

Comment: I wanted to open a chat to discuss this topic but I don't have privileges for that. Here is my email (remove blanks!): florian @ cosmoworx . de